# C++ Error Message *Member reference..* *Beginner*

Tags: c++

recieveing this error message when i'm coding this, anyone got any clue?

"member reference base type 'vector [10]' is not a structure or union"

tried to google it, but still no similar answer to my problem.

The dots is colored red in the program.

```
#include     <iostream>   
#include     <algorithm>
#include     <cstdlib>
#include     <cstring>
#include     <vector>
#include     <iterator>
#include     <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> lotteryNumVect[10];
    int lotteryNumArray[5] = {4, 13, 14, 24, 34};

    lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), lotteryNumArray, lotteryNumArray+3);

    lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin()+5, 44);

    cout << lotteryNumVect.at(5) << endl;

    lotteryNumVect.push_back(64);

    cout << "Final Value " << lotteryNumVect.back() << endl;

    lotteryNumVect.pop_back();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lotteryNumVect[10]` is an array of vectors, maybe you meant to create a vector with 10 items instead? `lotteryNumVect(10)`

Answer (score 2):

vector  lotteryNumVect[10];
You created an array of vectors here to declare a single vector do instead: 
vector  lotteryNumVect(10);